# "train" function Error in "caret" package R: "Please use column names for `x`"

Tags: r, r-caret

I am trying to use train function for Leave-One-Out (LOO) cross validation (LOOCV).

While

```
train(y~ x1, data = test, method="lm", trControl = trainControl(method = "LOOCV"))
```

works well, I need to write it in another format that I can put it in a for loop that I make as many as models that I want. But the following format does not work and give an error:

```
train(paste("y~", colnames(test[2])), data = test, method="lm", trControl = trainControl(method = "LOOCV"))
Error: Please use column names for x
```

But the same format in "lm" function works well:

```
lm(paste("y~", colnames(test[2])), data = test)
```

Can you please guide me how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution!

```
lm("y~x1", data=test)
```

works as same as

```
lm (y~x1, data=test)
```

But "y~x1" does not work in the train function.
Need to add '**as.formula**' before it:

```
train(as.formula("y~x", data=test, method="lm", trControl = trainControl(method = "LOOCV"))
```